# View not updating when using $controller service in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers.  The view is tied to the firstCtrl.  I'm trying to run the function in the second one so the view is updated. Function runs but view not updated.  Any ideas?

```
<div>{{people.length}}</div>



angular.module('myApp').controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var self = this;
  $scope.people = [];


  function getData() {
    $http.get('/people').then(function(res) {
      $scope.people = res.data;
    });
  }

  getData();
  $scope.getData = getData;

  self.getData = function(){
               $scope.getData();
      };
      return self;

});




angular.module('myApp').controller('secondCtrl', function( $controller, $scope, $http) {

    var firstCtrl= $controller('firstCtrl', { $scope: $scope.$new() });
    firstCtrl.getData(); //This runs but view is not updated above.
});
```

Comment: Seems like you're not passing data through scope in second controller

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  What am i suppose to pass?

Comment: Have a look at this plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/cuL3hc?p=preview Pass data you're getting through scope like $scope.data = firstCtrl.getData();

Comment: Thanks.  I see what you did there, however my factory has ajax calls...

Comment: So as you're making ajax call from `firstCtrl` . Does it helpful to you?

Comment: Ajax call seems to make it different. You can only assign the $scope variable in the promise.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has some problem with the $scope. So instead of pass data directly in the firstCtrl. I pass a callback to getData function and assign data to $scope.people in the callback.

Here is the working Plunker:

```
> http://plnkr.co/edit/QznxFL
```